# How to add JDBC connectors jar files to a portable Eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, jar

Where should I put the JDBC JAR files in order to be able to user them from Eclipse and be able to keep Eclipse portable (in Dropbox).

Answer (score 3):

Go to the folder in which tomcat is installed. Inside that go to the lib folder and put the jar file there.

You will also need to link this in eclipse.

1. Open eclipse IDE.
2. In the dynamic web design prespective, link the jar file by right clicking the project folder.

Comment: how this will make eclipse portable?